# Understanding 'CSS Tricks' Javascript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, module, resize

I am trying to improve my Javascript and understand the module posted here - http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

My code looks like this:

```
var
s,
ResizeContainer = {

    settings : {
        winWidth : $(window).width(),
        winHeight : $(window).height()
    },

    init : function() {
        s = this.settings
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions: function() {
        console.log(s.winWidth);
    }

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    (function()
    {
        ResizeContainer.init();
    })();
});

$(window).on('resize', function()
{
    ResizeContainer.init();
});
```

What I am trying to achieve using this module is to simply alert the window width when the doc is ready, which it does, and also when the window is resized, which it does not.

Can anyone help me understand why the window width is not updated on resize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K2Mfd/5/, you need to open the web inspector in console tab to see the results, basically you need to compute width and height each time:

```
settings : function(){
    return {
       winWidth : $(window).width(),
       winHeight : $(window).height()
    }
},
```

And don't forget to replace `settings` by `settings()` wherever you have it.

```
s = this.settings();
```

By the way, I think you don't need the:

```
(function(){})();
```

In each handler

Comment: thanks for the reply! So I think I essentially understood the concept of the module but it was updating the w/h that threw me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the post, I usually refer to, when deciding what module pattern is suitable for application I'm working on: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

This helped me not only with structuring my code, but also with reducing/removing global variables.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Based on the question, I believe understanding of JavaScript patterns is important, and therefore my answer.
Thanks for the reminder though @kleopatra, I am aware of that.